# InteractionAggregation Pipeline doesn't trigger in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics, aggregation

I am working on custom analytics aggregation in Sitecore 9.3. I have done all the code and configuration but my custom *CentralLoginProcessor* is not executing.

**config file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
<sitecore role:require="Standalone or Processing">
    <pipelines>
    <group groupName="analytics.aggregation">
        <pipelines>
        <interactions>
            <processor type="Documentation.Examples.CentralLoginProcessor, Documentation.Examples" />
        </interactions>
        </pipelines>
    </group>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**source code:**

```
namespace Documentation.Examples
{
    public class CentralLoginProcessor : InteractionAggregationPipelineProcessor
    {
        protected override void OnProcess(InteractionAggregationPipelineArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("xDB Started processing Login event", this);
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            VisitData visitData = VisitDataMapper.GetVisitData(args);
            if (visitData.SiteName == "centralsite")
            {}
        }
     }
}
```

Did I miss anything? Someone please help on this issue.

Comment: Can you login as admin user and go to /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to check if this config has been inserted properly? Make sure you've deployed the DLL to the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

This processor will automatically call after approx. 20 mins, if you need to run this processor, you must to force end session: HttpContext.Session.Abadon();